# Override Default Grails create-app Files

Tags: grails

Is there a way to replace the Grails default Config.groovy, BuildConfig.groovy, DataSource.groovy, etc. configuration files that are generated/copied when running grails create-app? I have several apps that all use the same or very similar configurations so I end up doing a lot of copying and pasting when starting a new one.

I looked into using external configuration files which might work, but I'd also like to replace the spring/resources.groovy and some of the views and css/js/images files as well which wouldn't be able to be done that way.

I saw where these files are located in $GRAILS_HOME/src, but changing those directly doesn't affect create-app (I'm assuming I'd need to rebuild grails for that to take affect).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way but it's a bit involved, and completely undocumented, so this will be our little secret.

The `create-app` and `create-plugin` scripts are actually quite simple. They create a new empty directory and extract some jar files from `GRAILS_HOME/grails-resources-<version>.jar` that contain the various project files, and unpack those into the project directory. Then `integrate-with --eclipse` is run to create IDE files for GGTS and for `create-app` the `wrapper` script is run to create `grailsw`, etc. unless you use the `--skip-wrapper` flag.

Towards the end of 2.3.0 development I added a check in the scripts for customized version of these jars and if one or more are found, they're used instead of the stock jars. To use this, create a folder in `$HOME/.grails/<version>` named `app-templates`. So for Grails 2.4.3 that'd be `$HOME/.grails/2.4.3/app-templates`. To avoid accidentally deleting this directory I'd actually create a symlink with that name pointing to a separate directory (e.g. `ln -s /path/to/app-templates.2.4.3 ~/.grails/2.4.3/app-templates`, but that's optional. You could also use symlinks to share one set of override jars for multiple version of Grails.

Unzip `$GRAILS_HOME/dist/grails-resources-2.4.3.jar` and you'll have 5 jar files: `grails-app-files.jar` (app-specific files), `grails-integration-files.jar` (files for the `integrate-with` script, e.g. Eclipse project files, IDEA project files, etc.), `grails-plugin-files.jar` (plugin-specific files), and `grails-shared-files.jar` (files used by both apps and plugins). Additionally you'll have a `grails-wrapper-support.jar` but this isn't something you'd typically want to customize.

Unzip each of the 4 jar files and make whatever changes you want. Some of the changes I tend to do are to delete a lot of comments from conf files, move `URLMappings.groovy` from the shared jar to the app jar since it's rarely needed in plugins, move `DataSource.groovy` from the shared jar into both the app and plugin jars and strip out most of the one that'll be used in plugins, and a few other changes. You can delete files, move them around between the jars, and add new files if you like.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you! Just to clarify, it won't read the unzipped files, I'll have to repackage them up, right? I assumed that was the case, but just wanted to be sure. Now to upgrade from Grails 2.2.1 so I can take advantage of this! :) Thanks again

Comment: Right, I forgot the last step which is to re-zip the unpacked directories and replace the old jar files with those. Use any zip tool you like to unpack and pack the jars, but be sure to keep the .jar extension and to keep the same directory structure when you re-pack.

Comment: One last comment, I noticed that `create-app` was pulling the JAR from a maven repo and since we have a local Artifactory repo we use to proxy dependencies and store local artifacts, I made changes as you described, packaged everything back up and deployed a local version to our repo. Running `create-app` works great for us now, and since it's in Artifactory we don't have to manually replace the JAR. Works great, thanks much!

Comment: Cool, that's a good way for a team to have a consistent override strategy. My approach is more appropriate for per-developer customization (which is still an option that can combined with this approach).